# How to transform some tags to another using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML:

```
<p>
   First level
   <p>
      Second level
      <p>
         Third level
      </p>
   </p>
</p>
```

I want to transform it using XSLT template and get the following result:

```
<b>
   First level
   <b>
      Second level
      <b>
         Third level
      </b>
   </b>
</b>
```

I want to preserve original structure. Note the text node.

How do I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="p">
    <b>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </b>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Correct, but the starting `//` operator is not needed in patterns.

Comment: Could you help me with another question related to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757431

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look.  If you feel my response answered your question feel free to accept it by clicking the check mark in the top left of my response.