# How to transform some tags to another using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml:

```
<box>
   <title>bold text</title>
   some text
</box>
```

and the following xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="box">
    <p style="background:red;">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
    <p style='background:green;'>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

And I got following:

```
<p style="background:red;"> </p>
<p style="background:green;">bold text</p>
some text
<p></p>
```

But I want following:

```
<p style="background:red;">
   <p style="background:green;">bold text</p>
   some text
</p>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You sure about that? Your stylesheet should produce your desired output.

Comment: You shouldn't get that output if the templates you posted are the only thing in your stylesheet.  Can you post the full XSLT?  There may be other templates causing the unwanted output to be generated.

Comment: Yep :( Maybe this is a bug of libxsl. (I use PHP to XSL transformation).

Comment: Damned! I was looking at the fireBug output, not at plain html. Plain HTML is correct. Sorry for question! :P

Comment: Nesting `<p>` elements inside each other isn't a particularly good idea. The HTML parser will try to sort it out by unnesting them, and this is what you are seeing in Firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run this xslt/xml I get this result:

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="box">
    <p style="background:red;">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <p style='background:green;'>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Xml Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<p style="background:red;">
   <p style="background:green;">bold text</p>
   some text
</p>
```

This is what you want correct?